# Pandas dropped row showing in plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, indexing, scipy

I am trying to make a heatmap.

I get my data out of a pipeline that class some rows as noisy, I decided to get a plot including them and a plot without them.

The problem I have: In the plot without the noisy rows I have blank line appearing (the same number of lines than rows removed).

Roughly The code looks like that (I can expand part if required I am trying to keep it shorts).
If needed I can provide a link with similar data publicly available.

```
data_frame = load_df_fromh5(file)  # load a data frame from the hdf5 output
noisy = [..] # a list which indicate which row are vector    

# I believe the problem being here:
noisy = [i for (i, v) in enumerate(noisy) if v == 1] # make a vector which indicates which index to remove
# drop the corresponding index
df_cells_noisy = df_cells[~df_cells.index.isin(noisy)].dropna(how="any")

#I tried an alternative method:
not_noisy  = [0 if e==1 else 1 for e in noisy)
df = df[np.array(not_noisy, dtype=bool)]

# then I made a clustering using scipy
Z = hierarchy.linkage(df, method="average", metric="canberra", optimal_ordering=True)
df = df.reindex(hierarchy.leaves_list(Z))

# the I plot using the df variable 
# quit long function I believe the problem being upstream.
plot(df)
```

The plot is quite long but I believe it works well because the problem only shows with the no noisy data frame.

IMO I believe somehow pandas keep information about the deleted rows and that they are plotted as a blank line. Any help is welcome.

Context:
Those are single-cell data of copy number anomaly (abnormalities of the number of copy of genomic segment)
Rows represent individuals (here individuals cells) columns represents for the genomic interval the number of copy (2 for vanilla (except sexual chromosome)).